# program crashes while reading from a file. C

Tags: c, file

the code down there is to copy a text file into an another.
its failing. assertion error (stream !=NULL)

```
fp = fopen("quiz.txt", "w");
fp2 = fopen("output.txt", "r");

number_of_conversions = fscanf(fp2, "%c", &c);

while (number_of_conversions != 0 && number_of_conversions != EOF){
    fputc(c,fp);
    number_of_conversions = fscanf(fp2, "%c", &c);
}
fclose(fp2); 
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: the code part is screwerd up.

` fp = fopen("quiz.txt", "w");

 fp2 = fopen("output.txt", "r");


 number_of_conversions = fscanf(fp2, "%c", &c);

 while (number_of_conversions != 0 && number_of_conversions != EOF){
  fputc(c,fp);

   number_of_conversions = fscanf(fp2, "%c", &c);
 }

 fclose(fp2);

 fclose(fp); `

Comment: I see no `assert` in that code. And it seems strange that you're reading from a file called `output.txt`.

Comment: i already wrote data to it now am writing that data back to input file.

Comment: ok, I suggest checking `fp` and `fp2` to make sure that they are `!= NULL` before trying to use them.

Comment: is still get the same error.

Comment: What do you mean "is still get the same error"?  Did you check that fopen did not fail?

Answer (score 0):

Always check for the sucess of [`fopen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) before using the returned file pointer.

If `fopen()` fails, it will return NULL and using that further will lead to  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). So, put a NULL check immediately after the `fopen()` call(s). Also, FWIW, if `fopen()` fails, there is no open `FILE *` and you don't need to call `fclose()`, either.